# How to create the namespaces for web2py application database

Tags: google-app-engine, web2py

I am new to web2py and google app engine, i tried to develop simple CRUD operations web2py application have one database table like db.regiser and deploy this application in google app engine in two different regions and now i need to create the namespaces for this application database to access the two different regions users to perform the CRUD operations on their own namespaces without affecting the main db, and how to create the namespaces to the database for web2py application.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's in the documentation (though it is noted in the [scaffolding app code](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/R-2.14.6/applications/welcome/models/db.py#L37)), but you can specify the namespace in the connection string:

```
db = DAL('google:datastore+ndb://mynamespace')
```

Also, as a possible alternative, note that the web2py DAL includes its own [multi-tenancy functionality](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Common-fields-and-multi-tenancy). Using this method, your code would be portable should you choose a different hosting/datastore option in the future.

Comment: @Anthony-here i have n number of regions like region 1 and region 2 ... region n, is it possible to pass the region namespace name to connection string while the user is login into system or its automatically adjust the namespace based on the user login as per the region ?

Comment: Well, the user records are stored in the database, so for a user to log in, you must already have a connection to the database and therefore know the namespace. So, you either need to store the `Auth` records in a separate shared datastore, or you need some other way to identify the region/namespace (e.g., via the URL).